# Cannot write to word from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

Recently I created a method in C# in an APS.Net form that is used to take data from TextBoxes in ASP.net page and export them to a pre-defined bookmarks in Word. I tested it worked fine both on my desktop computer and also was working fine in the hosted environment. But recently it is not working. It is not exporting to word anymore. However, it works fine in local computer but not when hosted. The permission is OK and there is not other problem.

Now I'm stacked and don't know what to do. Is there any hint or help please?

Comment: post the method code please.

Comment: The code is very long. It is very difficult to load.

Comment: it's ok hope someone here can help you, but it's always better to put any part of your code in your questions to make it easier for others to help you find solutions faster.

Comment: Are you using Word automation or openXML (or something similar)?

Comment: i am using word automation. It takes data from dataset and put into word bookmarks.